# Как воткнуть влешку usb в usb-c

Tags: usb, mac

Вчера купил себе флешку, но не подумал что она не влезет в мой мак. Подскажите что делать.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не соответсвует тематике сообщества

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Купи переходник и через него подключи флешку!

Answer (score 2):

Купи переходник, я покупал оригинальный за 1800 рублей, не оригинальный еще дешевле стоит

Comment: Ну типа с Алика заказать

Comment: Уверен, что в любом магазине электроники будет переходник, как оригинальный. так и нет. Я в Мвидео покупал